# Script for creating a tile-pyramid from a wms service

Tags: wms, tiles, tilecache

Given a WMS service, is there a ready-made script that, for a given extent, creates a tile-pyramid that is compliant with:

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#tilelayer

That is urls on the form:

```
'http://{s}.somedomain.com/blabla/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```

I think what I want is MapProxy. I can configure a TMS layer that caches my WMS service, and copy the files that it generates.

Answer (score 3):

[MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) is certainly a good option. If it is just a script you require, [TileCache](http://tilecache.org/) is another option. It's not as configurable as MapProxy, but it is a nice, light-weight solution. If you are already serving your WMS using GeoServer, then I'd recommend [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

with openlayers you can get your wms xyz result as below code. i think with some changes this code will work for you.

```
leaflet_wms.getURL(Bounds)


function getURL (bounds) {
   var res = this.map.getResolution();
   var x = Math.round ((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
   var y = Math.round ((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
   var z = this.map.getZoom();

   var path = z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
   var url = this.url;
    if (url instanceof Array) {
       url = this.selectUrl(path, url);
   }
   return url + path;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a script that _generates_ the tiles. Not quite sure what the idea with the javascript you posted is?